# PyOCD doesn't find Nu-Link2-Me probe on my NuMaker board

Tags: embedded, nuvoton

**Note: Why this question is not off-topic**
*Some people seem to think this question is off-topic, and it would be better suited for Super User. Please give me a chance to explain why that's not the case.*

*The question is not about "general computing hardware" but about "embedded software". In the topic of "embedded software", there are tons of questions on StackOverflow related to OpenOCD, a popular open-source tool to connect your computer to embedded software development boards. All these questions are considered totally okay for StackOverflow. My question on this page is about PyOCD - an emerging OpenOCD alternative. So if you vote to close this question, then please also vote to close the 565 (!) other questions about OpenOCD too ;-)*

---

I've got a **NuMaker-M032SE V1.3** board from Nuvoton that I'm trying to flash/debug with **PyOCD**. It's my first time I'm experimenting with PyOCD and with Nuvoton chips. Unfortunately, **PyOCD** cannot find the device. I'll go step-by-step through the whole procedure. Please tell me what I did wrong.

---

### 1. My system

I'm running 64-bit Windows 10 on my desktop computer. I've got **Python 3.8** and recently installed the latest **PyOCD** development version from a cloned GitHub repository (see https://github.com/mbedmicro/pyOCD).

---

### 2 Install Microcontroller board

*Note: this paragraph is simply to show you the background situation, before I move on to explain the actual problem I got with PyOCD*

I've got a Nuvoton **NuMaker-M032SE V1.3** microcontroller board:

[image]

This board has a **Nu-Link2-Me V1.0** probe on the right side. The first time I connect my board to my computer nothing really happened. So I figured out I had to install the **Nuvoton ICP tool** that comes with the **Nu-Link USB Driver 1.6**:

[image]

You can download the **Nuvoton ICP tool** here: https://www.nuvoton.com/hq/support/tool-and-software/development-tool-hardware/programmer/
When I first start the sofware, I see this:

[image]

And I get a request to update the firmware on the **Nu-Link2-Me V1.0** probe:

[image]

I click OK and wait for the firmware update to complete. I plug out and back in the board. Windows clearly notices the device:

[image]

I can also see the device in my **Control Panel** > **Device Manager**. It's listed under **Universal Serial Bus Controllers** as **Nuvoton Nu-Link2 USB**:

[image]

---

### 3 Prepare PyOCD

**PyOCD** has a few built-in targets. But not the Nuvoton chip I got. So I consulted the documentation at https://github.com/mbedmicro/pyOCD/blob/master/docs/target_support.md and learn that I need to download a **pack** from http://www.keil.com/dd2/pack/ . That's where I download the `Nuvoton ARM Cortex-M NuMicro Family Device Support` pack:

[image]

Because I downloaded the pack manually, I know that I'll have to add the parameter `--pack="C:/path/to/pack/Nuvoton.NuMicro_DFP.1.3.5.pack"` to every **PyOCD** command, to ensure that **PyOCD** can access this pack whenever it needs to.

---

### 4. Connect PyOCD with Nuvoton board

I believe my microcontroller board is properly installed to go on to the final step: connect **PyOCD** to the Nuvoton microcontroller board.

First I want **PyOCD** to find the board. I issue the following command in a Windows console:

```sh
$ pyocd list --pack="C:/path/to/pack/Nuvoton.NuMicro_DFP.1.3.5.pack"
```

Unfortunately, I get the response:

```sh
No available debug probes are connected
```

I tried a few times, both with and without the `--pack` parameter. I always get the same error message.

**Note:**
I had expected to see something like:

```sh
      #   Probe              Unique ID
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
      0   ARM CMSIS-DAP v1   000000800a0c882800000000000000000000000097969902
```

That's the output I get when I issue the `$ pyocd list` command and I have my **SWDAP** probe connected to my computer. The **SWDAP** is the official probe from ARM (see https://os.mbed.com/components/SWDAP-LPC11U35/) that runs the **DAPLink** firmware (see https://github.com/ARMmbed/DAPLink).

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close as off-topic as well because the question seems to be about general computing hardware and software and it doesn't directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [Super User](https://superuser.com/).

Comment: Hi @TiagosupportsGoFundMonica, thank you for your response. The question is not about "general computing hardware" but about "embedded software". In the topic of "embedded software", there are tons of questions on StackOverflow related to OpenOCD, a popular open-source tool to connect your computer to embedded software development boards. All these questions are considered totally okay for StackOverflow. My question on this page is about PyOCD - an emerging OpenOCD alternative.

Comment: I really don't understand why this question was closed, as the author says it is about embedded computing and he has a specific issue he wants help with. Plus, the level of detail of the steps to reproduce the issue is great.

Comment: It's certainly possible to ask on-topic questions about pyocd, the problem is that *this* question is off topic, as it is asked from a *user perspective*.  An on-topic question asked by a *software developer* would be one showing serious effort to *understand* and *debug* the means which the open-source program pyocd should be using to identify and connect with the probe.

Comment: Hi @ChrisStratton, thanks for sharing your reasons. However, I disagree. I have done my best to *understand and debug* the issue in PyOCD. Proof is that I downloaded the Nuvoton pack and issue the command in PyOCD to show all connected probes.
Also your accusation that my job description is "not doing embedded development but write support guides" is plain wrong. It's true that I'm trying to support many probes, and it's also a fact that some of these probes are still causing many issues.

Comment: You "disagree" because you repeatedly fail to understand the problem all of your questions trip over.  The Nuvoton pack has *nothing* to do with the issue of communication between pyocd and the probe.  Just as in your previous questions about openocd, **you need to understand the precise mechanism (libusb or whatever) which the tool should be using to communicate with the probe itself.**  If (as in your self answer) the manufacturer doesn't think this is going to work yet, that may require digging into and modifying the ocd code guided by packet sniffing the manufacturer's tool.

Comment: Hi @ChrisStratton, I've opened a private chat room for the two of us here on StackOverflow. Let's continue the discussion there. Please...

Comment: I don't understand why this topic is such an issue. Regardless of other topics posted by the user, there seems to me to be a degree of investigation done to resolve the issue here.

Comment: @Sid - it might look like that to someone unfamiliar with the technical issue here, but in actuality this user repeatedly skips over the technical issue that is at the core of all of their questions:  The USB device must be exposed by the operating system to the tool, the tool must know how to identify it, and must know how to talk to it.  Nothing on this page digs into that specific problem.  The user needs to spend time studying the open *source code* of pycod which could potentially communicate with this probe, and may end up having to modify or extend it to support a new version.

Comment: Hi @ChrisStratton, I'm still waiting for you in the StackOverflow chat window: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203473/room-for-k-mulier-and-chris-stratton

Comment: @ChrisStratton: you actually say I'm not entitled to ask questions on OpenOCD/PyOCD connection issues because I did not study the OpenOCD/PyOCD source code. If that is the standard you judge by, then you'll have a lot of work to close down thousands of questions.

Comment: Hey Chris, Kristof is creating an SDK for newcomers in the embedded programming and debugging world so he is probably dealing with real world scenarios of his users, may want to create a guide for them, and bring them to the StackExchange. But your trolling seems to push people away, so even Kristof is now advancing on GitHub not here. Not everyone has your level of expertise, also some people may have different understaning of the problem wich you does not seem to understand. Closing questions/threads is not the answer :-(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got a reply from Nuvoton. Apparently the **NuMaker-M032SE V1.3** board is not yet supported in PyOCD at the time of writing (02 Dec 2019). At the moment, only **NuMaker M252/M263** boards are supported.

Nuvoton will make efforts to support these boards in PyOCD too, in the future.

Comment: This could be something so simple as a different USB PID, or something so serious as an entirely different communication protocol.  Unless you decide to approach the problem as a *software developer* by understanding and debugging at code / packet level the way that the open source pyocd tool communicates with USB-based SWD probes, you'll have to take the manufacturer's answer that it is "not supported" as a stopping point.

Comment: Hi @ChrisStratton, are you willing to talk to me in the private chat window? I'd really want to sort this problem out with you.

Comment: Hi @ChrisStratton, here is the link to the private chat window: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203473/room-for-k-mulier-and-chris-stratton

Comment: Hey @K.Mulier I think there are some NuMaker boards supported by pyOCD and ARM MBED OS, if the core is similar porting them should be fairly easy :-)